# Linux shared memory only allow read access

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

I have a parent process that allocates shared memory and writes to it.
It also starts child processes that only read the shared memory. However I don't have any control over the insights of those child processes. They are written by other programmers. These child processes are not supposed to write on the shared memory. So I wondered if I can allow them read permissions, but not write access.

However with `shmget` you can only specify general permission without being able to distinguish between read and write access.

I also thought about switching to `shm_open` & `mmap` as it seems that you can open the shared memory with `O_RDONLY` which forces the use of `PROT_READ` (read-only access) in the `mmap` call. Is it somehow possible to create two file descriptors with `shm_open` in the parent process: one with `O_RDONLY` and one with `O_RDWR` and then passing the `O_RDONLY` one to the child processes which can then map it into their process space? Of course, the children shouldn't have the permission to open the shared memory on their own by using `shm_open` because that would enable them to open it with `O_RDWR`.

Or did I get the concept wrong? Is it what I want even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[T]he children shouldn't have the permission to open the shared memory on their own" implies that this is a security boundary, so shared memory is probably not appropriate. There are all sorts of odd synchronisation issues involved with shared memory, and you really want all users to play nicely with each other.

`shm_open()` is little more than a helper function to generate the name of a rendezvous file within "/dev/shm" and `open()` it. You then get to `ftruncate()` and `mmap()` it yourself. The `mmap()` call will fail if you ask for `PROT_WRITE` on a read-only file descriptor, which gives you the finer control that you seek.

So one thing you can do is `shm_open(..., O_RDWR)` in the parent and set up a writable mapping for the parent before closing the handle, then `shm_open(..., O_RDONLY)` to get a read-only file handle which you will pass to the children, followed by a `shm_unlink()` so that the children cannot then re-open the file. Children then use this read-only file handle for their own mappings.

If a child were to perform a read-write `shm_open()` after the parent has done a `shm_unlink()`, it would get a new rendezvous file and thus cannot affect the mapping in the parent or other children. However, a determined attacker could try and exploit a race condition when the parent creates a fresh mapping. How untrustworthy are these child processes?

You do not say if these child processes are separate executables. If they are, you will want to want to use `fcntl()` to duplicate the fd to a well-known fd number that is not marked close-on-exec so that the child can find it when it is launched.

I do however recommend you reconsider your need for shared memory if you do not trust child processes, and look at sending messages over a pipe or socketpair instead.

Comment: Well I can't really trust these children. They are small apps the user of my program can install (from foreign sources).
However there aren't any security issues here. The worst thing that could happen is that a misbehaving process causes malfunctions or crashes in the other processes by invalidating the data on the shared memory block. I doubt that anyone would want to write such an app on purpose. I just want to protect apps from bugs in other apps.

Comment: "and look at sending messages over a pipe or socketpair instead"
I already use message queues for small data that requires more security. However I think they're ineffective for big data chunks? Especially because you'd have to send it to each process seperately.
Anyway I think I just have a try on your suggested method.