# Is shared memory with an untrusted process safe?

Tags: linux, multithreading, security, operating-system, shared-memory

I'm trying to create an x86 Linux program that runs with elevated privileges but can also run potentially unsafe code in a child process and communicate with it via shared memory, mainly for performance reasons. My idea looks like this:

- The root process allocates memory with `mmap` and `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS`
- It forks, the child process calls `setuid` and loads user-supplied code afterwards.
- The child process cannot be trusted anymore.

What are the pitfalls of accessing the shared memory afterwards? Obviously the child process can supply invalid data and change it at any time, but can it actually harm the parent process in other ways like blocking the memory access, even killing it off or anything comparable?

Or is it safe to use e.g. memcpy()?

Are atomic operations safe? sem_timedwait?

Answer (score 2):

If you only use the memory for simple operations, like memcpy, the child cannot directly harm you, but if you really don't trust them what is the point in sharing?

Putting a semaphore in the memory is a bad idea; again, you can't trust them, which means, well, you can't trust them.  Semaphores, mutexes, condvars, ... only work in a high degree of trust.  Message passing is better, but doesn't need shared memory.

The worst I can imagine is a minor denial of service attack.   During I/O, pages are typically unavailable for access.  If your child forked many copies of itself, and managed to continuously directio the shared pages, it could substantively disrupt the parent's execution progress.

There are people with more devious imaginations than mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you have a reference about the semaphores?

Comment: I'm trying to design a fault-tolerant multi-user server architecture. The children can be trusted in theory, but it is not unlikely that they get hacked and in that case it must not be possible to hack or bring down the parent process.

Comment: Not really, but when you look at *trust*, one approach is to synthesize an attack.  The good actor uses the semaphore as expected; the bad actor acquires but never releases.   While the good actor might be able to protect themselves with timeout-based operations; the utility of the semaphore is still lost, unless the good actor turns bad.  You can construct similar cases for other shared synchronization primitives.

Comment: Yes, if one child turns bad, it is obviously no longer useful. But this can be tolerated as long as it does not disrupt the rest of the system. I'll try to compile a list of references regarding this topic.

Comment: Look at minix3; it is more forward looking in these areas than most other systems.   Also, picking apart the nuances of golang's message passing in terms of rate and dispatch limiting probably worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I will try to collect whatever I can find about the limitations of shared memory IPC with a hostile process and countermeasures.

Please correct me if you find a mistake or something better!

#### Use  read-only-mapping for unidirectional communication

http://selinuxsymposium.org/2007/papers/11-SecureIPC.pdf

In section 3.3 this paper states that shared memory can be created by process A with Read/Write access and process B can be restricted to read access only.

If the root process wants to send data to the child process that contains fragile data structures that must not be manipulated by the child, it could use a read-only mapping.

But I am not sure if the above only applies to SELinux, how to actually do it or if it can be done with mmap only.

Something similar is stated here:

[Shared Memory when it's for read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249037/shared-memory-when-its-for-read-only?rq=1)

#### Synchronization issues

[Linux shared memory only allow read access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002305/linux-shared-memory-only-allow-read-access)

"There are all sorts of odd synchronisation issues involved with shared memory".

Unfortunately no more details.

#### pkeys - Memory protection keys

https://lwn.net/Articles/466304/

Intel Skylake only

#### 2011 LWN article comparing various IPC mechanisms

https://lwn.net/Articles/466304/

#### LWN article about Chromium communicating with seccomp sandbox

https://lwn.net/Articles/347547/

#### Chromium sandboxing FAQ

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox_faq.md#But-can_t-malware-just-infect-the-process-at-the-other-end-of-the-pipe-or-shared-memory

*"But can't malware just infect the process at the other end of the pipe or shared memory?
Yes, it might, if there‘s a bug there. The key point is that it’s easier to write and analyze a correct IPC mechanism than, say, a web browser engine. Strive to make the IPC code as simple as possible, and have it reviewed by others."*

So Chromium is doing some kind of shared memory IPC!